# Issue with Google Classroom courses.courseWork.list "field_mask: Unknown field mask values: individual_students_options"

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client, google-classroom

I need to query the partial fields for **courseWork.list** and **courseWork.get** so I am passing this value in fields as described in the documentation. But `courseWork(individualStudentsOptions)` API call returns a error:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "field_mask: Unknown field mask values: individual_students_options",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "field_mask",
            "description": "Unknown field mask values: individual_students_options"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In other experiments, for example `courseWork(id)` everything is fine and the API call returns this:

```json
{
  "courseWork": [
    {
      "id": "93359557635"
    },
    {
      "id": "93359557700"
    },
...
 ]
}
```

So please help me how to fill in the field of **individualStudentsOptions** ?

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you calling this api?

This is how we do it here:

```
 String studentUser = "student@gmail.com";
                IndividualStudentsOptions individualStudentsOptions = new IndividualStudentsOptions();
                ArrayList<String> studentIdList = new ArrayList<>();
                studentIdList.add(studentUser);
                individualStudentsOptions.setStudentIds(studentIdList);

                CourseWork courseWork = new CourseWork()
                        .setCourseId(course.getId())
                        .setTitle("My course work")
                        .setDescription("desc")
                        .setMaxPoints(100.0)
                        .setDueDate(date)
                        .setDueTime(timeOfDay)
                        .setAssigneeMode("INDIVIDUAL_STUDENTS")
                        .setIndividualStudentsOptions(individualStudentsOptions)
                        .setWorkType("ASSIGNMENT")
                        .setState("PUBLISHED");

                courseWork = service.courses().courseWork().create(course.getId(), courseWork).execute();
```